# bitbake: How to include .so build by one recipe into another recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

How do I include a shared library in another bitbake recipe that makes use of a makefile to compile a program depending on the shared library?

So i have:

- bitbake recipe for compiling a shared library(mylib.so)
- bitbake recipe for a small program(myprog) depending on the library(mylib.so)

How do link the shared library to this small program?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up proper dependency. If mylib.so is required to compile myprog, add package that supplies mylib.so to compile time dependencies of myprog.

Usually package name is the same as corresponding recipe's name, so if the recipe that produces mylib.so is named `mylib_1.0.bb`, add the following line to the recipe for myprog:

```
DEPENDS += "mylib"
```

If mylib.so is used only at runtime, use

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "mylib"
```

Comment: I allready had the above code in the myprog recipe. But since I use a makefile to compile the myprog code I am missing the compile time reference  in my makefile to the library. Basically I am missing the correct gcc -I and -L flags/tags

Comment: Please add at least recipe for your library to the original post.